# ¿Como crear un botón alarma en Android?

Tags: java, android

Necesito crear un botón y definirle una hora (alarma). El caso es que cuando el usuario de la app dé click en el botón, se active dicha alarma.

He intentado y buscado más, pero todos utilizan `TimePicker`. El código que tengo es más o menos así:

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by diego on 11/06/2017.
 */

public class alarm {

    private int horas;
    private int minutos;
    private TimePicker timePicker;
    private Button button_alarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_alarm);
    private AlarmManager alarmaManager;
    private PendingIntent alarmaIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

        Context context = null;
        alarmaManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
        alarmaIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        button_alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                horas = timePicker.getHour(14);
                minutos = timePicker.getMinute();
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, horas);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutos);
            }
        });
    }

    private void findViewById(int button_alarm) {

        button_alarm

    }

    public AlarmManager getAlarmaManager() {
        return alarmaManager;public void setContentView(int contentView) {
        this.contentView = contentView;
    }
    }

    public void setAlarmaManager(AlarmManager alarmaManager) {
        this.alarmaManager = alarmaManager;
    }

    public PendingIntent getAlarmaIntent() {
        return alarmaIntent;
    }

    public void setAlarmaIntent(PendingIntent alarmaIntent) {
        this.alarmaIntent = alarmaIntent;
    }


}
```

Comment: no quieres que tenga un dialogo,entonecs que este hardcoded la hora?

Comment: Quiero crear como un despertador por así decirlo, pero que tenga ya las horas definidas en los botones

Answer (score 0):

Prácticamente tienes el código terminado, en el `calendar` le indicas la hora, minutos y segundos:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12); //hora en formato 24h
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00); //minuto
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00); //segundo
alarmaManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, alarmaIntent); //Repetir cada 24 horas
```